# Client tries to find server in the same LAN

Tags: rest, networking

In my scenario I want to create a webservice running on a Raspberry Pi which offers a restful API. Beside a webapp made with AngularJS I would like to know, how I could find such my server in that is in the same LAN? Like inside an Android application for example?

Some Android apps have the functionality to seek a media server in the LAN and stream movies, music and other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually accomlished with [**`multicast DNS`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), which is implemented by Apple with the fancy name [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)).

Comment: This was just an idea to implement it my current application but implementation in my language exists. Thanks for the tip.I'll give it a try.